# Axios POST Error: Request failed with status code 419

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I am trying to make a post request with Axios + Laravel 7.
And I got this error message:

> Error: Request failed with status code 419

My Javascrip code:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrf_token
};
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

var formEditEmpresa = document.getElementById("formeditEmpresa");

function validareditEmpresa() {

    var formData = new FormData(formEditEmpresa);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: "editarLoja",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        data: formData,
    })
        .then(res => {
            // listarChamados.innerHTML = res.data;
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the headers to this syntax:

```
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
```

As show in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf).

Comment: I am not using Jquery, and when I put this, I receive an error message saying taht $ is not declared.

Comment: Try not using .common, as in:
Axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.csrf_token

Answer (score 0):

i added this in the .env laravel file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://127.0.0.1:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

http://127.0.0.1:3000 is the virtual domain name of my frontend application